# MiniProfiler with a ReliableSqlConnection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

Hi I tried to get this working by  following the database profiling instruction on the MiniProfiler site however I can't get it work.

I want to profile a ReliableSqlConnection for use in Azure.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of profiling a SqlConnection (using it to instantiate a `ProfiledDbConnection`) cannot be used in this case, since `ReliableSqlConnection` implements `IDbConnection` but does not extend `DbConnection`.

However, you should still be able to use [`SimpleProfiledConnection`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/d58d4ad41d4052ed02b13f644a72f24a87f9cf3b/StackExchange.Profiling/Data/SimpleProfiledConnection.cs) instead. You can instantiate this as follows:

```
using StackExchange.Profiling.Data;

ReliableSqlConnection conn = GetAzureConnection();
var profiledConn = new SimpleProfiledConnection(conn, MiniProfiler.Current);
```

You would then be able to use `ProfiledConn` in place of your `ReliableSqlConnection`, with all Db commands being profiled.

You could also do this on a command-by-command basis by creating a [`SimpleProfiledCommand`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/d58d4ad41d4052ed02b13f644a72f24a87f9cf3b/StackExchange.Profiling/Data/SimpleProfiledCommand.cs) using a very similar constructor.